# Can not resolve symbol of mocked object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

So to learn more about unit tests and mocking i created the following simple interface which i want to mock and test in my unit test:

```
namespace TestProjekt
{
    public interface ICsvFile
    {
        string FileName { get; }

        int GetFileSize();
    }
}
```

and the a test using NUnit and Moq

```
namespace NUnitTests
{
    using Moq;
    using NUnit.Framework;
    using TestProjekt;

    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTests1
    {

        private const string FILENAME = "0030001744_14224429_valuereport_20140527000012_1104.csv";


        private const int FILESIZE = 155;

        [Test]
        public void ExampleTest()
        {
            var file = new Mock<ICsvFile>();
            file.Setup(m => m.GetFileSize()).Returns(FILESIZE);
            file.SetupGet(m => m.FileName).Returns(FILENAME);

            Assert.AreEqual(FILENAME, file.FileName);
            Assert.AreEqual(FILESIZE, file.GetFileSize);
        }
    }
}
```

I made this based on a [Tutorial i found online and quite interesting](http://www.agile-code.com/blog/mocking-with-moq/). The Problem is, that Visual Studio cant resolve the Method and Property or anything else i `setup` on the mocked object.

All dlls are referenced correctly. It must be a super simply thing but i just cant figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your system under test? You would typically want to use mock objects when you are unit testing (hence, in isolation) the class/module that depends on the mocked entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you encountered a compile error. The reason is that you used the properties directly from the instance of the `Mock<ICsvFile>` type. Instead, you should use like `file.Object.FileName`. The `Object` property represents the mocked instance of `ICsvFile`.

Modify your code as the following.

```
Assert.AreEqual(FILENAME, file.Object.FileName);
Assert.AreEqual(FILESIZE, file.Object.GetFileSize);
```